# What is the difference between fundamental group and fundamental groupoid?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, fundamental-groups

I came across this article https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fundamental+groupoid#Browno6 but still I did not get what is the difference between fundamental group and the fundamental groupooid and when they are the same.

Could someone explain this to me in a simple way please?

Comment: One is a group, the other is a category.  One cares about a specific basepoint, the other doesn't.

Comment: Topology aside, do you understand the difference between a group and a groupoid?

Comment: Take the extreme example of a disconnected space where the basepoint means you only have information of one of the components but without having to pick a specific basepoint you still have that information.

Comment: @Karl no I know the difference algebraically and I think the notion of groupoid used here is not an algebraic one but a categorical one

Comment: What does "the notion of groupoid used here is not an algebraic one but a categorical one" mean? There is only one notion of a groupoid.

Comment: In the fundamental group, you have chosen a base point and the elements are equivalence classes of loops at that point. Because they are based at that point, you know that you can multiply (concatenate) any two loops. In the fundamental groupoid, the elements are equivalence classes of paths, but since you don't have any restrictions on their endpoints, you can multiply some of them but not others. (So it's a groupoid: every element is invertible, but not every product $a*b$ is defined.)

Comment: To answer one of your specific questions: they will be the same when your space has one point in it.

Comment: @Thorgott No, unfortunately there are (at least) two: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)). There is some discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948610/whats-the-preferred-term-researchers-like-to-use-in-the-theory-of-magmas-groupo).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh well, I wasn't aware that magmas are also sometimes called groupoids. Thanks for the info. Then, to the OP: the categorical notion of groupoid is meant. You will have to understand this notion first in order to sensibly answer this question.

Comment: @Thorgott here is the link to what I meant https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Groupoid.html